# Operation of algorithm using while loop with third power conditioning

Tags: algorithm, loops, complexity-theory, cubic

could somebody please shed some light on what this piece of code is actually doing? I think it should be fairly straightforward but I am stuck at the moment, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 read n;
 i := 1;
 while (i * i * i) <= n do
     i := i + 1;
 output (i-1)
```

Also how could one calculate the complexity of this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It increments `i` until `i³` is greater than `n`. Therefore `i-1` will be `floor(cube_root(n))`, and that's what's returned.

The running time is proportional to the cube root of `n`, since that's how many iterations of the loop are performed.

Comment: Thanks, so I suppose this is a pretty efficient algorithm having O(n^1/3).. Would perhaps a recursive analogous be more efficient?

Comment: It's possible to do much better with an [iterative method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root#Numerical_methods) such as Newton's or Halley's. As it says you need to take care in choosing your initial guess, but it should be a lot faster.